# glGenBuffers 2 names?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer

I have been implementing a small opengl application that I based off of this tutorial:
http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-4-entering-the-third-dimension/

I understand most of the code but I am really confused about this line:

```
glGenBuffers(2, &BufferIds[1]);
```

Which is then followed by

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferIds[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size,  &theModel->theMesh.pos[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I assume I only need one free name/id to bind my buffer data to, but if I change

```
 glGenBuffers(2,
```

to

```
 glGenBuffers(1,
```

The buffer fails to bind and nothing works.

BufferIds is 3 in size (GLuint BufferIds[3]).  I would like to make it BufferIds[2] using the first slot for the VAO & the second for the VBO.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &BufferIds[0]); 
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not generate the VAO"); 
glBindVertexArray(BufferIds[0]); 
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not bind the VAO"); 

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); 

ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not enable vertex attributes"); 

glGenBuffers(2, &BufferIds[1]);  //if this gets from changed 2 to 1 ...
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not generate the buffer objects"); 

int size = theModel->theMesh.pos.size() * sizeof(theModel->theMesh.pos[0]) ; 

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferIds[1]); 
ExitOnGLError("ERROR: Could not bind the VBO to the VAO");  // ...this error triggers
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, &theModel->theMesh.pos[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest a different variable name. Using `BufferIds` for storing IDs of buffers and of vertex arrays wouldn't pass my code review.

Comment: I agree about the BufferIds name, its not mine its from the tutorial, i'm going to do a re-write once I get this working and understand what's going on.  I just need to know how to works to write clean code.

Comment: Seriously though, this is more profound than simply what you call the array. In OpenGL 3, names are tied to their function. Prior to this, you could use a name generated with `glGenTextures (...)` (or a unique unsigned integer value picked at random for that matter) to identify a VBO if you wanted. You do not want to create an array which has names serving completely different functions because if you forget which index belongs to which type of object all you have left is an array of meaningless unsigned integers in GL3; you could not even use `glIs___` to figure out what something was.

Comment: Because the set of VAOs might have a name **23** and the set of all allocated VBOs might also have a name **23**. `glIsVertexArray (...)` would return true for the name **23** and so would `glIsVertexBuffer (...)`. Each set of object types has its own pool of names that may overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you pass BufferIds[1] to glBindBuffer. Index 1 is actually the second element, so your code crashes when you only create one buffer.

Try that:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &BufferIds[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferIds[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry I revised my question.  The first slot is already in use for the VOA  I then use slot 1 which makes sense.  I just don't get why I have to have it generate two names.

Comment: Right, my bad. I didn't realize you were also calling glGenBuffers with the second element.

Comment: Another thought: what happens to BufferIds[2]? Do you use it later? Maybe the call to glGenBuffer is supposed to initialize both fields [1] and [2].

Comment: I don't see anywhere that it is used, and the error that occurs, and the error that is thrown occurs immediately I call  glGenBuffers(2, &BufferIds[0]);